# Angular: Type string is not assignable to type date

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, I wrote a code as below.

```
obj.created_date = formatDate(obj.created_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm', 'en-US'); // initial value of created_date is 2022-08-12T20:17:46.00.000+01.00
```

FYI, the type of `created_date` is `Date`.

However, in here, I see the error as - type 'string' is not assignable to type 'date'.

If I amend `new Date` before the `formatDate(...)` then I see the unwanted result. How can I get the result with the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"?

Comment: pipe = new DatePipe('en-US') and then obj.created_date = this.pipe.transform(obj.created_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formatDate return a string

as obj.created_date is of type Date you can't affect a string in it

you will have to affect formatDate result in a String type variable